# how to apply two kind of css to one control, one for internet explorer, another for firefox and chrome

Tags: asp.net, css

how to apply two kind of css to one control, one for internet explorer, another for firefox and chrome

just in internet explorer the contentplaceholder move to another place today, past days no problem

```
<div id="content" style="margin-top:28px; margin-left: 240px; border:0px solid;">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>


<!--[if IE]>
#hellocss
{
    margin-top:-600px; margin-left: 100px; border:0px solid;
}
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>
#hellocss
{
    margin-top:28px; margin-left: 240px; border:0px solid;
}
<![endif]-->
```

i meet a big problem, it can be negative number for margin-top in internet explorer

Comment: Conditional comments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: do it have "else" conditional comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in CSS like this

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link href="Styles/IEstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: i meet a big problem, i can not use negative number to margin top to adjust position

Comment: negative margin looks different problem. Can you share url or something else like html or css where you are facing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Give the ContentPlaceHolder a class:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder CssClass="contentPlaceHolderClass" id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

and at the top of the page use conditional CSS to define this style: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use underscore(_) in starting of your property name so that it will be only applicable to IE.

like
style="style="margin-top:28px; margin-left: 240px; border:0px solid;**_margin-top:10px; _margin-left: 240px; _border:0px solid;**">

Comment: i meet a big problem, i can not use negative number to margin top to adjust position

Comment: in testing site, internet explorer position is correct, after deploy, got this problem